# AngularJS $watch not working

Tags: angularjs

i've been stuck on the same matter for 4 days, re-coded everything from scratch over and over again.
I've attempted calling $scope.$apply(), yet to no avail.

This is as simple as it can get, yet i cannot get it to work (I know, that i could simply bind a module to DOM element, but I have the need to use more complex functions later).

Any help?

[CodePen Link](http://codepen.io/imm0rta1693/pen/zHtvK/)

```
  var watch = function ($scope) {
    $scope.$watch('in1', function(newVal, oldVal) {
      if (!newVal) return;
      console.log ('New value is: ' + newVal + '\nOld Value is: ' + oldVal);
      $scope.getResult = newVal;
  });
};

angular.module ('testApp', [])
  .controller('testCtrl', watch);
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO :-) Just wanted to mention that since the problem turned out to be a typo (ng-module instead of ng-model) it will probably get closed.

Comment: I feel like hitting myself in the face with a brick right now. Thanks to everyone who pointed that out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty easy, your `input` has a `ng-module` attribute, it's supposed to be `ng-model`

```
ng-model="in1"
```

Working code pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eyDxI

Answer (score 0):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/okKbl

You need to change `ng-module` to `ng-model`